# Is Kotlin's primary constructor's argument private at all or only for the Java code?

Tags: java, kotlin

When I use data class or the regular class and set the argument to its constructor it generates getter/setter in the Java code but in Kotlin we can achieve it by the variable name. Is it private in Java only or Kotlin replaces its getter/setter by the variable name?

The class

```
class Person(var name: String)
```

When calling it from kotlin code as you can see I call name variable

```
fun main() {
    print(Person("Mohammed").name)
}
```

When calling it from Java as you can see I call the method, not the variable

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Person("Mohammed").getName());
    }
```

but I can not use

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Person("Mohammed").name);
    }
```

IntelliJ shows that `name` is private.

So, the question is - Is the argument private at all or only for the Java code?
Does Kotlin replace its getter/setter by the variable name then reverse it at runtime?

Comment: A) please consider to give some feedback whether your question is answered, for example by accepting an answer B) welcome to upvote levels ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with that misconception in the question:

> The question is is the argument is private at all or only for the Java code?

There is no such thing as "private for java only".

Reminder: no matter if you write Kotlin and use kotlinc, or Java with javac, in the end, your source code gets compiled into a JVM **class** file. And the content and information within that file determines what "users" can do with your class.

And when I compile your Person.kt class, and run javap, that is what shows up:

```
> javap Person.class
Compiled from "Person.kt"
public final class Person {
  public final java.lang.String getName();
  public final void setName(java.lang.String);
  public Person(java.lang.String);
}
```

The point is: as you can see, there is a **getter** for that field.

Beyond that, there is also *meta information* within the class file that tells a **Kotlin** compiler that this class "is" a Kotlin class.

Thus the Kotlin compiler allows you to use `somePerson.name` "directly".